# Extensão para Chrome, Opera e Firefox

Tags: debate, stackexchange-button

### Instalando:

Instalação pelas **lojas oficiais** dos navegadores:

- [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stackexchangenotification/jcjhifljlkmoodmebfiimpoofdehnhia?hl=pt-BR)
- [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/pt-BR/firefox/addon/stackexchangenotifications/)
- [Opera](https://addons.opera.com/pt/extensions/details/stackexchange-notifications/)

### O que a extensão faz?

- Avisa sobre novas mensagens da caixa de Entrada (*inbox*)
- Avisa sobre suas novas conquistas (*achievements*), como pontos, medalhas, novos privilégios, etc
- Editor com opção de expandir pra toda tela (área do view-port)
- Lightbox para imagens das perguntas e respostas
- Salvar salas de chat para acesso rápido

Desta maneira eu posso participar dos sites *SOpt* mais ativamente sem necessitar estar no site, ou seja pode navegar em outros sites que não são da "rede" e saberá quando chegar mensagens e a reputação mudar.

### Screenshots

- Notificações de mensagens novas "Caixa de entrada" (inbox) e "Realizações" (achievements)

  [image: inbox and achivements in your browser]
- Editor de texto em fullscreen:

  [image: editor fullscreen]
- Lightbox para fotos:

  [image: galeria]
- Tema Black para evitar contraste em navegadores que usam temas ou fundo escuro (como por exemplo usuários do https://github.com/StylishThemes/StackOverflow-Dark):

  [image: tema Black]
- Copiar códigos:

  [image: copy codes]
- Salvar sala:

  [image: save room]
- Atalhos para salas salvas no popup (antes e depois):

  [image: shortcut rooms]

### Diferenças no Meta e no site principal

O editor em fullscreen pode confundir as vezes o site que estamos, mesmo no editor "nativo" eu já vi usuários se confundindo, eu mesmo certa vez postei uma resposta no Meta por ter duas abas abertas no campo de resposta, uma no site principal e outra no Meta, acabei por postar as respostas de maneira invertida, então as diferenças são estas:

- Sites principais:

  [image: editor nos sites principais]
- Sites "Meta":

  [image: editor nos sites meta]

---

### FAQ:

- **O que me levou a criar está extensão (add-on):**

  Eu costumo trabalhar longas horas por dia e eventualmente acessava o *SOpt* quando recebia alguma mensagem através do aplicativo para iPhone oficial da SE, mas o barulho incomodava um pouco e as vezes atrapalha outras pessoas, além de causar sensação no ambiente de trabalho que eu estava trocando sms, whatsapp, devido a nem todos no escritório entenderem a minha profissão.

  Outro motivo que me levou a criar a extensão foi pela praticidade de estar tudo no mesmo lugar.
- **Por que o addon está em inglês?**

  A maioria dos dados veem já pré-formatados do próprio *StackExchange* e ainda não é possível alterar isto, mas estou trabalhando.

### O projeto

O projeto é open-source (código aberto) e está disponível no [GitHub](https://github.com/brcontainer/stack-exchange-notifications)

- Repositório do Projeto [GitHub](https://github.com/brcontainer/stack-exchange-notifications)
- Problemas que encontrar ou sugestões envie para [Issues](https://github.com/brcontainer/stack-exchange-notifications/issues)
- Você também pode modificar e melhorar o código fonte enviando para [PullRequests](https://github.com/brcontainer/stack-exchange-notifications/pulls)

Espero que apreciem e que está extensão facilite o uso do site pra você.

> ### StackApps:
>
> Link no StackApps:
>
> https://stackapps.com/questions/6455/stack-exchange-notifications-inbox-and-achievements-opera-and-firefox

Comment: **Relacionado:** http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4033/3635

Comment: Muito legal! Já considerou publicar também no http://stackapps.com?

Comment: @bfavaretto obrigado, sim já pensei, só não postei por causa que acredito que os apps lá sejam voltados ao uso da API, mas eu abrir uma questão sobre aplicativos que não usam a API: http://stackapps.com/questions/6446/app-without-api-and-legal-issues

Comment: Muito legal mesmo! Amanhã vou tentar instalar aqui seguindo o guia. 
Parabéns! Edit: instalei no opera só pra ver, muito legal mesmo!

Comment: Show de bola Guilherme :) Espero ter ela no Firefox em breve.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento excelente trabalho, parabéns! Falta agora por notificações de novas perguntas das tags favoritas ;)

Comment: Vc usa o avatar do L!!! \o/

Comment: Muito bom! Parabéns!

Comment: @JorgeB. a ideia da extensão é funcionar semelhante ao "stackechange-botão", ao menos não notei tal funcionalidade sobre as tags favoritas. Como o SE-botão funciona para todos os sites, ele dificilmente irá trazer funcionalidades de sites/comunidades especificas, mas estou estudando bem a API oficial e se com ela, eu puder trazer sobre qualquer site que você tenha conta as perguntas com tags favoritas, prometo que irei fazer :)

Comment: Se der ao menos para trazer as perguntas novas sobre uma tag escolhida. Depois podia dar para escolher várias tags.

Comment: Pro chrome ainda não foi disponibilizado?

Comment: @diegofm Chrome não é gratuito pra colocar extensões, tem uma taxa de 3 dolares, sei que é pouco e é apenas uma vez, mas fiquei com preguiça de ir até o banco pedir um cartão internacional pra usar o paypal hehehe, assim que possivel vou pagar e colocar disponivel ;) ... todavia tem uma dica ali de como instalar no chrome.

Comment: Isso eu li kkk, quis dizer se pode instalar direto via arquivo cxr(?), Sem baixar pela loja.

Comment: Nao tinha visto o trecho, vou tentar instalar aqui. Acho q o git é bloqueado.

Comment: @diegofm não, o chorme bloqueia se vier de fontes diferentes do Store, tem que fazer como esta no link http://www.tecmundo.com.br/tutorial/26055-google-chrome-como-instalar-extensoes-que-nao-estao-na-web-store.htm ou seja instalar como se você também fosse desenvolvedor ;)

Comment: Parabéns @GuilhermeNascimento. Dá orgulho de ter esse menino na mesma organização que eu no Github :p

Comment: Esta funcionando bem no novo FF? Fiquei sabendo que a versão 57 deixou muitos plugins incompatíveis

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado sim, ele é feito em WebExtension, que é a tecnologia mais recente para criar extensões, compativel com FF, Chrome, Edge e outros baseado em Chromium... O FF esta indo finalmente pelo caminho do Cross :) (desde o 47 na verdade), só ficaram legados e agora no 57 removidos os que foram escritos em XUL (e no tal SDK), felizmente eu já estava ciente disto desde o FF 47 hehehe. Pode usar tranquilamente.

Comment: bom trabalho :)