# O Stack Overflow possui configuração de notificação?

Tags: suporte

Existe alguma configuração na plataforma do Stack Overflow, que habilite algum efeito sonoro de notificação?

Gostaria de ser notificado de alguma forma, as vezes estou online, porém somente sei que alguém respondeu alguma pergunta ou fez algum comentário quando clico na aba do navegador.

Não encontrei nada nas configurações e esse é um recurso importante, até mesmo para melhorar a interação entres os usuários.

Comment: Uma sugestão se usa Opera ou Firefox: [*Extensão para Chrome, Opera e Firefox*](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4075/3635) (chrome store em breve)

Comment: Eu uso google chrome =( tem alguem desenvolvendo para esse navegador ?

Comment: Pretendo disponibilizar em breve, todavia você pode procurar algo assim para chrome em https://stackapps.com

Comment: Você pode baixar o app da StackExchange e receber notificações no seu smartphone. Meu principal portal de entrada para o SOpt é via aplicativo

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado eu uso muito mais o mac air do que o smartphone, nesse caso o ideal seria um solução pro chrome mesmo, ou talvez mudar de navegador rsrs.

Comment: @JonathasB.Cavalcante às vezes eu uso o smartphone para gerenciar notificações. Por exemplo, estou fazendo uma pergunta e apareceu aqui na caixa de entrada antes de aparecer no browser. Eu sei que é gambiarra, não o ideal, mas funciona =]

Comment: `até mesmo para melhorar a interação entres os usuários.` Stack Overflow não é uma rede social.

Answer (score 2):

Eu uso no meu celular o aplicativo do StackExchange

https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8

Quando recebo respostas ou comentários aparece um push notification aqui.